# Firebase Xamarin foreach Snapshot Children

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-realtime-database

I've using Firebase for my Xamarin app , using Xamarin.Firebase beta 32

My project have error by:

```
  foreach (DataSnapshot postSnapShot in snapshot.Children)
 {
         // Do something
 }
```

The error is :

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Java.Lang.IIterable' because 'Java.Lang.IIterable' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: Actually the error is pretty clear, isn't it?

Comment: See my answer for a similar question at: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/44783540/2959575](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44783540/2959575)

Answer (score 0):

You can import System.linq in your file and then iterate throw snapshot.Childen.ToEnumerable()