# Xamarin Firebase How to Read a single Child Record with No Key into an .AsObservable .Subscribe snapshot

Tags: c#, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, observable, subscribe

My Firebase Child subscribe below never gets into the snapp lambda brackets... I never get my Writeline statements written to the console, so my subscription does not seem to be working. The Child Parameters is a single record in FB with no key. This single record contains program "Parameters" that are monitored during the program run from an interface.

**In Firebase**

```
ControllerData > Controller_1 > Parameters

Parameters
  Cycle: 60
  LWritten: 158793607
  aug: true
  fan: false
  ign: true
```

In my Xamarin **FirebaseHelper.cs**

```
    public async Task<Parameter> GetParameters()
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("^^^^^^^^^^ In GetParameters() ^^^^^^^^^^");


        firebase.Child(ChildParams).OrderByKey().AsObservable<Parameter>().Subscribe(snapp =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("F.I.A. is Fan: " + snapp.Object.fan + " Ign: " + snapp.Object.ign + " Aug: " + snapp.Object.aug);
            ViewParameterModel.LWritten = snapp.Object.LWritten;
            ViewParameterModel.Aug = snapp.Object.aug;
            ViewParameterModel.Fan = snapp.Object.fan;
            ViewParameterModel.Ign = snapp.Object.ign;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Mode: [" + ViewParameterModel.Mode + "]<<--Mode here");
        });



        return null;
    }
```

When I run the program... all I get in the Console Writeline is the:

**^^^^^^^^^^ In GetParameters() ^^^^^^^^^^**

So I know I'm getting there but my Firebase call is not working... Is there some special way I need to snapshot this single Parameter child record since it has no key?

any help would be appreciated.

thanks,
Brian

Comment: you want to get data from firebase? If yes, I suggest you can take a look this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500686/how-to-get-value-from-firebase-in-xamarin

Comment: Thanks Cherry, I did try this but this example link appears to be too old for Xamarin. FirebaseDataBase is not an option nor is Firebase.Database.Instance.  I am using NuGet FirebaseDatabase.net by Step Up Labs. is there some other nuget this is referring to?

Comment: I figured out a workaround by re-adding the single parameter record with a Firebase $Key. it did not have a key before. So it will be the only record in parameters.

Comment: Glad to hear that you have one solution, please post one reply to share your answer and mark it as answer, it is beneficial to others to find this answer, thanks.